# How to pull data using HQL code through the repository using 2 conditions

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hql

```
@Repository
public interface MeetupRepository extends CrudRepository<Meetup, Long> {

    List<Meetup> findAll();

    @Query(value = "select * from meetup join meetup_timetable " +
            "on meetup.id=meetup_timetable.meetup_id where meetup_timetable.employee_id = :employee_id", nativeQuery = true)

    List<Meetup> getAllByEmployeeId(@Param("employee_id") String employeeId);
 }
```

How to add a second condition to the code above in @Query - (meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId).stream().
filter(m -> m.getEndDate().compareTo(startDate) > 0 && m.getStartDate().compareTo(endDate) < 0)),    to pull the necessary data from the database at once?

```
public Map<String, Boolean> checkingIntersectionMeetup(List<String> employeesId, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {

        //We check if they have any meetings that overlap with the one they want to invite them to

        Map<String, Boolean> intersect = new HashMap<>(employeesId.size());

       for (String employeeId : employeesId) {
            List<Meetup> overlappingMeetups = meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId).stream().
                    filter(m -> m.getEndDate().compareTo(startDate) > 0 && m.getStartDate().compareTo(endDate) < 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (overlappingMeetups.isEmpty()) {
                intersect.put(employeeId, false);
            } else intersect.put(employeeId, true);
        }
        return intersect;
```

I tried to add a secondary condition, but an empty Resultlist was returned?